# single intellisense file for multiple js function files?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I have functions1.js, functions2.js and functions3.js.  Each has a function, funcA, funcB and funcC respectively.  I created a file called "functions.intellisense.js" and added it to _reference.js.  I then added a reference to _reference.js in my test.js file.

Why doesn't intellisense work?

**functions.intellisense.js**

```
intellisense.annotate(funcA, function () {
    /// <signature>
    /// <summary>Function A</summary>
    /// </signature>
});

intellisense.annotate(funcC, function () {
    /// <signature>
    /// <summary>Function A</summary>
    /// <param name="message">message</param>
    /// </signature>
});
```

**_reference.js**

```
/// <reference path="functions.intellisense.js" />
```

**functions1.js**

```
function funcA() {
    alert("this is function A");
}
```

**functions3.js**

```
function funcC(message) {
    alert("this is function C " + mesage);
}
```

**test.js**

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/_reference.js" />
func  //<--- expecting this to show intellisense
```

Is it even possible to do this?  I'd like to do it for a couple reasons, first of all just *combining* documentation.  Secondly, I'd like to be able to pre-document functions.  Maybe prepend ideas with "TODO" so like if I haven't written the Test.Add() function, I could still put it in the intellisense file and it would popup with "TODO: Adds a test".

Comment: Hi Scott - can you paste in the contents of your _references.js file? - Jordan, Microsoft Visual Studio PM

Comment: /// <reference path="functions.intellisense.js" />

Comment: It looks like it works if I reference functions1.js and functions3.js at the beginning of functions.intellisense.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented already about how you have to setup your references - you have to declare functions before they're passed to intellisense.annotate if you want them to appear in IntelliSense. The function declaration drives the IntelliSense completion list, the annotate call updates the documentation for an already declared function.

> I'd like to be able to pre-document functions. Maybe prepend ideas with "TODO" so like if I haven't written the Test.Add() function, I could still put it in the intellisense file and it would popup with "TODO: Adds a test".

You could do this by writing your own helper for IntelliSense, for example:

```
function stubFunction(functionName, annotation) {
    if (!window[functionName]) {
        window[functionName] = function () { };
    }
    intellisense.annotate(window[functionName], annotation);
}
```

Calling `stubFunction` would create the stub function declaration and annotate it in one call:

```
stubFunction("funcA", function () {
    /// <signature>
    /// <summary>Function A does something important</summary>
    /// </signature>
});
```

Now, if you type `func` in the editor, you'll see funcA appear in the completion list with your documentation comments.

This `stubFunction` utility could be placed in functions.intellisense.js and then used in that file to pre-document all your functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I modify functions.intellisense.js to include references to the script files containing the actual functions, it seems to work as expected.

```
/// <reference path="functions1.js" />
/// <reference path="functions3.js" />
intellisense.annotate(funcA, function () {
    /// <signature>
    /// <summary>Function A does something important</summary>
    /// </signature>
});

intellisense.annotate(funcC, function () {
    /// <signature>
    /// <summary>Function C does something equally important</summary>
    /// <param name="message">message</param>
    /// </signature>
});
```

I was hoping to avoid this since as I said the functions may be stubs for functions that haven't even been written yet, but this still works.  I'll wait to accept this answer to see if Jordan ha any more recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for all the details in your update. The intellisense.annotate calls will only work if the target functions are already declared before the annotate calls are made. So, as you found, by referencing the functions1.js and functions3.js files before the calls to intellisense.annotate, funcA and funcC are declared and can be annotated. I'd recommend putting those two references into _reference.js right above line that includes functions.intellisense.js. Then all of your references are maintained in one location.